# Include META-INF resources in a javadoc jar in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project and I create a regular classes jar, and also a javadoc and sources jar.

In all three I need to include a META-INF folder that includes a LICENSE and NOTICE file.

I have this folder with files under src/main/resources/

the classes jar and the sources jar work correctly but I need to also get them added to the javadoc jar.

How can I fix the javadocJar task to include META-INF folder?

```
// custom tasks for creating source/javadoc jars
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

// add javadoc/source jar tasks as artifacts
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get what I needed by adding a copy task but it would be good if I could select just the META-INF directory in case I add more directories under resources.

```
// custom tasks for creating source/javadoc jars
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task copyResources(type: Copy, dependsOn:javadoc) {
    into javadoc.destinationDir
    from sourceSets.main.resources
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:copyResources) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```